# Can't override CSS with child theme

Tags: css, child-theme

So far everything has worked alright with !important, but I can't seem to be able to change the bottom margin of a H5 title. On this link http://soniromanov.com/pricing/ the plans Basic, Deluxe and Premium have an annoying bottom margin of 30px. I've tried with:

.pricing-title h5 {
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}

But that doesn't fix it, sorry for my limited knowledge on CSS, please help if possible.

Comment: The page has some kind of (copy protection?) feature that makes using normal inspection tools impossible. I get a "function disabled" dialogue whenever I try to right-click on an element.

Comment: Sorry buddy, you should be able to right-click now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are using a more specific identifier in the theme on the homepage.

try this one:

```
.be-section .be-row:not(:last-child) .column-block h5:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
}
```

you can change the margin to whatever you want, of course.

okay try this:

```
#main .be-section .be-row:not(:last-child) .column-block h5:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 5px !important;
}
```

Comment: Tried it, didn't work again. The site is running with this included in the child theme. I'm ready to give up on this until the author fixes it.

Comment: is there anything else in the child theme stylesheet?  put this code at the end.  are you sure you have no other errors in your stylesheet that would stop this from posting?

Comment: This is the style.css I have in the child theme http://pastebin.com/7nwTVBdr , the code that was recommended is last.

Comment: yeah, they definitely didn't enqueue correctly.   Try the 2nd code above.  I've made it more specific, so it should override.

Comment: You are a savior, after all this days being annoyed by a bottom margin. Can't thank you enough.

Comment: I've been there.  Glad it worked and good luck on the site.  It's looking good.